# How to use 1 side wilcoxon rank sum test python

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, probability, scipy.stats

I have 2 lists, and I would like to check the wilcoxon rank sum test.

I saw that there is [scipy.stats.ranksums](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ranksums.html) library, but it only show the 2 sided test.

How can I do 1 sided test in python?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I checked seems like there is only one-sided for wilcoxon signed rank test.

Maybe not the most ideal, but you can use the wilcox.test from R by calling rpy2:

```
import numpy as np
from rpy2.robjects import FloatVector
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
stats = importr('stats')

x = np.random.poisson(1,size=20)
y = np.random.poisson(3,size=20)

test = stats.wilcox_test(FloatVector(x),FloatVector(y),alternative='less')
d = { key : test.rx2(key)[0] for key in ['statistic','p.value','alternative'] }
d
```

Comment: In the end I decided to multiply the threshold by 2, since the distribution is standard normal, I can calculate the 2 sided test and divide it by 2.